# Populate data in maximum 5 Columns then move to next Row

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a report format as below.

**Data Set**

[image]

| Customer | Order Number | Item name | Product Number | Color | Type | Size | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | OR-01 | ABC 111 Description | ABC 111 | RED | ZZ | 50 | 4 |
| Orange | OR-01 | ABC 111 Description | ABC 111 | RED | ZZ | 49 | 1 |
| Orange | OR-01 | ABC 111 Description | ABC 111 | RED | ZZ | 48 | 3 |
| Orange | OR-01 | ABC 222 Description | ABC 222 | BLACK | ZA | 51 | 2 |
| Orange | OR-01 | ABC 222 Description | ABC 222 | BLACK | ZA | 50 | 1 |
| Orange | OR-01 | ABC 222 Description | ABC 222 | BLUE | ZA | 49 | 2 |
| Orange | AA_01 | ABC 134 Description | ABC 134 | GREEN | ZD | 62 | 1 |
| Orange | BB~02 | ABC 145 Description | ABC 145 | ORANGE | ZE | 23 | 15 |
| Orange | BB~02 | ABC 145 Description | ABC 145 | ORANGE | ZE | 20 | 1 |
| Orange | BB~02 | ABC 333 Description | ABC 333 | RED | AA | 13 | 3 |

**Report Format**

[image]

| TT | Name | Product No | Color | Type | Unit | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | Count | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OR-01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ABC 111 Description | ABC 111 | RED | ZZ | cm | 50 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 49 | 8 | 393 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | 48 | 48 | 48 |  |  |  |  |
|  | ABC 222 Description | ABC 222 | BLACK | ZA | cm | 51 | 51 | 50 |  |  | 3 | 152 |
|  | ABC 222 Description | ABC 222 | BLUE | ZA | cm | 49 | 49 |  |  |  | 2 | 98 |
| 2 | AA_01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ABC 134 Description | ABC 134 | GREEN | ZD | cm | 62 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 62 |
| 3 | BB~02 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ABC 145 Description | ABC 145 | ORANGE | ZE | cm | 23 x 15 |  | 20 |  |  | 16 | 365 |
|  | ABC 333 Description | ABC 333 | RED | AA | cm | 13 | 13 | 13 |  |  | 3 | 39 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | TOTAL: | 33 | 1,109 |

Data set and Report Format are in different tabs. If the number of Quantity is big such as over 10 above, instead of listing it out, I want it to be put it as Size x Quantity (i.e. 23 x 15)

I was thinking that it may be easy to use loop to grab data in each row instead of checking the different number of Quantity using the following codes:

```
Sub CopyData() 

    Dim xRow As Long 
    Dim VInSertNum As Variant 
    xRow = 1

    Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "") 
        VInSertNum = Cells(xRow, "N") 
        If ((VInSertNum > 1) And IsNumeric(VInSertNum)) Then 
            Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "N")).Copy
            Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + VInSertNum - 1, "N")).Select 
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown 
            xRow = xRow + VInSertNum - 1
        End If 
        xRow = xRow + 1 
    Loop 

End Sub
```

I still don't know how to populate the Size data for only 5 times from Column G to Column K then continue inputting the Size data in the next row without inputting Name, Product No, Color, Type, Unit data.

Comment: Just curious, from your data sample, it looks like something like this : one product number will always have one name, one type and one unit. Will the data possible something like this.... (?) ---> ProdNum : ABC 111, type : zz, aa, az (three types), type zz color : red, blue - type aa color: pink - type az color : yellow, brown. Type zz red color unit : cm, mtr - type zz blue color unit : mm, km ... and so on. Please CMIIW.

Comment: If you are using an array, you decide if it contains column name or not, you can also control it in a way, that it dumps data in numeric positions (row, col) you want, with if, else inclusive. Is your repetition is only 5 times each? On another note, why wouldn't a pivot table work for you?

Comment: 1) In the data there is the column "Customer" which is not present in the Report. 2) In the Report there is the "Unit" column which does not exist in the data. .......Questions: a)The sum "TOTAL" is for each "Customer"? b) Is there a product with more than one "Unit"? If so, are the sums on the right also grouped by "Unit" ?